# iOS, Why is fetchedResult automatically updating itself when i modify the contents of MutableArray created from it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm making use of FetchedResultController stuff for my tableViewController, once i get the results, I'm creating an NSArray with the fetched objects

```
self.sortedArray = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

Now, I get all the results as desired but then when I make changes to the objects within self.sorted array, say..

```
Product *product = [self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
product.date = newDate;
bla bla blaaaa
```

note: product is an instance of the entity that was fetched.

Now, when i try  to access the old, unmodified object from the fetched result,

```
Product *actualProduct = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

it gives me the updated version. I'm not saving context before this.

Also, i cannot use

```
[self.moc refreshObject:product mergeChanges:NO];
```

because different fields of the same object is updated using other controls, so i need to track all changes to same object and also need to have reference to the original one.

I tried the same by creating a separate NSMubtableArray, and even with NSArray.. gives me the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store the fetchedObjects in an array, you are just storing a reference to the array. The array stores references to the objects it has. So when you modify these objects, the array will be pointing to the modified object. If you don't want to change the original object, do something like this or create a brand new Product object and copy the values from [self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] and modify it.

```
Product *product = [[self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] copy];
product.date = newDate;
...
```

You might have to override copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone of NSObject if your custom object is elaborate, like it has more objects within. Read more about copying objects here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ObjectCopying.html

Answer (score 0):

Because it is referencing to the same object. If you want to modify the MO you can create another MOC whose its parent context is the one you don't want to modify (yet.) Then, when you're ready to make changes, you save that child context which will propagate its changes to the parent context.